# I can't install rmagick gem on windows

Tags: ruby, windows, ruby-on-rails-3, imagemagick, rmagick

I used ruby 1.9.2 and rails 3.0.3. iam trying to install rmagick gem but when i run `bundle install` I got an error tells me:

```
Installing rmagick (2.12.1) with native extensions c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/site_ruby
/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:529:in `rescue in block in build_extensions': ERROR
: Failed to build gem native extension. (Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError)

       c:/Ruby192/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... yes
checking for stdint.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
       --with-opt-dir
       --without-opt-dir
       --with-opt-include
       --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
       --with-opt-lib
       --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
       --with-make-prog
       --without-make-prog
       --srcdir=.
       --curdir
       --ruby=c:/Ruby192/bin/ruby
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:368:in `try_do': The complier failed to genera
te an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
       from c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:452:in `try_cpp'
       from c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:834:in `block in have_header'
       from c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:693:in `block in checking_for'
       from c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:280:in `block (2 levels) in postp
one'
       from c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
       from c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:280:in `block in postpone'
       from c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
       from c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:276:in `postpone'
       from c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:692:in `checking_for'
       from c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:833:in `have_header'
       from extconf.rb:171:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rmagick-2
.12.1 for inspection.
Results logged to c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rmagick-2.12.1/ext/RMagick
/gem_make.out
       from c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:507:in `b
lock in build_extensions'
       from c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:482:in `e
ach'
       from c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:482:in `b
uild_extensions'
       from c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:156:in `i
nstall'
       from c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/sour
ce.rb:96:in `install'
       from c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/inst
aller.rb:55:in `block in run'
       from c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/spec
_set.rb:12:in `block in each'
       from c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/spec
_set.rb:12:in `each'
       from c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/spec
_set.rb:12:in `each'
       from c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/inst
aller.rb:44:in `run'
       from c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/inst
aller.rb:8:in `install'
       from c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/cli.
rb:226:in `install'
       from c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/vend
or/thor/task.rb:22:in `run'
       from c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/vend
or/thor/invocation.rb:118:in `invoke_task'
       from c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/vend
or/thor.rb:246:in `dispatch'
       from c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/vend
or/thor/base.rb:389:in `start'
       from c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.10/bin/bundle:13:in
`<top (required)>'
       from c:/Ruby192/bin/bundle:19:in `load'
       from c:/Ruby192/bin/bundle:19:in `<main>'
```

I installed ruby from http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/ with development kit and the latest version of ImageMagick. I tried to set rmagick configurations (lib and include directories) but I still get the same error

any help? any thoughts to solve the issue?

Comment: Here is a video that show a step by step tutorial on how to install the RMagik RubyGem On Windows 7 http://youtu.be/gEWAVlNCKhg [http://youtu.be/gEWAVlNCKhg](http://youtu.be/gEWAVlNCKhg)

Comment: Late at the party. Check out this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39513938/1903781) on how to install `rmagik` on windows 10.

Answer (score 15):

Prerequisites:
Ruby > 1.8.6
DevKit (any version)
No other ImageMagick installation or PATH entry

Step 1:
Installing ImageMagick:

Download ImageMagick:
http://imagemagick.spd.co.il/binaries/ImageMagick-6.8.0-3-Q16-windows-dll.exe

Install ImageMagick:
*Important: The installation path should NOT contain any spaces.
Ideally select “C:\ImageMagick″

Please make sure to select the below options:

> Add application directory to your path system
>   Install development headers and libraries for C and C++

Step 2:
Installing rmagick:

Use the following command to install rmagick gem:

```
gem install rmagick --platform=ruby -- --with-opt-lib=c:/ImageMagick/lib --with-opt-include=c:/ImageMagick/include
```

via-

http://shoobm.wordpress.com/2013/01/03/installing-rmagick-gem-on-windows-7/

Comment: Windows binaries of ImageMagick can be found here: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/binary-releases.php#windows

Answer (score 1):

I have [the same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21112092/how-install-rmagick-in-windows-xp-with-ruby-1-9-3/21112876#21112876), my environment was:

```
windows XP (x32)
ruby 1.9.3p484 (2013-11-22) [i386-mingw32]
DevKit-tdm-32-4.5.2-20111229-1559-sfx
ImageMagick-6.8.8-2-Q8-x64-static.exe
```

I install rmagik gem successfully, after reinstalling of ImageMagick from v6.8.8 to 6.6.7.
It was just a problem of incompatibility versions...

Answer (score 0):

Use **rmagick-win32** gem, and it doesn't need ImageMagick separately. This is bundled.

please have a look: http://rmagick.rubyforge.org/install-faq.html#win

Comment: AFAIK, this project is no longer being maintained :( the windows version is even older. Still if you want to use them find it here http://rubyforge.org/projects/rmagick/

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/rubyinstaller/browse_thread/thread/c29da64804d0ee4a/) in RubyInstaller group that points to our [Tutorials page](https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Tutorials) where you can find [this blog post](http://phosphor-escence.blogspot.com/2010/10/install-rmagick-on-mingw-and-msys.html) describing the installation method.

Comment: I've downloaded 6.6.4 Q16, but it has no `Install development headers` checkbox. Fresh version doesn't have it neither.

Comment: Here is screenshot: http://img.leprosorium.com/1221636 So after installation I don't see any *.h there.

Comment: I've responded this before on Stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6473853/ruby-on-rails-rmagick-on-windows-7/6477787#comment-7615667

Comment: Hint: you're not downloading the right version of ImageMagick.

Answer (score 0):

First of all clear your path environment variables. (This is the main step that people often skip, but very important). This is the main reason for the error you're facing.

Then install the rails installer (2.0.0) from here : http://railsinstaller.org/en

It'll set up ruby, rails, and everything else you need.
This will also set up your environment path variables for you as well.

Next install imagemagick 6.7.9.9 or lower and while installing check the option to include C headers. Make sure you install it within the rails installer folder.

Then type this in your command prompt  `path=c:\RailsInstaller\ImageMagick-6.7.9-Q8;%path%` or whatever version you have.

Then type

```
gem install rmagick -- '--with-opt-dir="c:\RailsInstaller\ImageMagick-6.7.9-Q8"'
```

Finally edit C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby2.0.0\setup_environment.bat to include the path to ImageMagic

At line 25: `SET PATH=c:\RailsInstaller\ImageMagick-6.7.9-Q8;` or whatever version you have